# Run a single test multiple times using maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a TestNG unit test that is intermittently failing. Is there a way to run a single unit test multiple times using the surefire plugin? If not, are there any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

Comment: create a new test method with a loop that calls your original method...

Comment: I don't know your code or project but i would first try to understand (and correct) why the tests fails intermittently... A test that you cannot rely on is very odd behaviour.

Comment: +1 to Lucas (though I don't seem to have a comment voting button right now).   Also, of course, intermittent failures are a serious code smell - I'd recommend spending less time on test design and more time on figuring out why your test is failing.

Comment: Does @Test(invocationCount=50) work with surefire plugin?

Comment: @CPerkins. I hear ya with the code smell, but the problem ended up being in the test.

Comment: @BillMan interesting.  Incidentally, it's ok here to accept your own answer since it will give later questioners the answer they seek rather than having to read comments.

Answer (score 6):

Once way I found is:

```
@Test(invocationCount = 100)
```